# How to connect Google App Engine (with Flask) to MySQL 1st Gen in Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-python

I have MySQL 1st generation database on Google Cloud SQL.
I am developing Web app with App Engine using Flask but unable to connect to databases which is on Cloud SQL.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have done it with MySQL 2nd generation